# XMLHttpRequest not defined in Manifest v3

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I had made a chrome extension in `v2` which i'm updating in `v3`

My Code

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
  item = {};
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    const fileName = xhr
      .getResponseHeader("content-disposition")
      .split("filename=")[1]
      .replace(/["']/g, "");
    console.log(fileName);
    item.blobData = this.response;
    item.filename = fileName;
    item.masterid = up;
    uploadCandidateResumeToPortal(item, sendResponse);
  }
};
xhr.open("GET", href1);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.send();
console.log(item);
```

is there any way to write this code in `fetch()`, or is there any other solution

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined